# how to display category name not id ,in browsing bar, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, browser, categories

I have many categories . so when I am viewing them I want to be able to see that categories name , not the id of the category.

At this moment I have like this.

http://postimage.org/image/5fb5uzhzd/

But I want after categories/category_name  .

I don't want that You say me everything, I just need some tip. So I could do the research.

Does this funcionality is somehow connected to the routes ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem to achieve that. You will find all the explanation you need to implement this feature in this [Railscasts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid?view=asciicast).

Or you can do it manually by following this other [Railscasts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url-revised).

Answer (score 0):

If the category_name is something that can be placed in url (like no spaces and so) you can achieve that by simply overriding `to_param` method in your model

```
class Category
  def to_param
    category_name
  end
end
```